# use getByRole to select gridcell with particular description

Tags: react-testing-library, testing-library

I have some tabular data with the headers ('Type', 'Name').  I would like to select all items in column 'name', to check if they contain a search string. Each item in that column has the role 'gridcell', and the description 'Name'. See attached image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONW4N.png).

`getByRole('gridcell', {description: /name/i})` doesn't work. I've looked through the typescript declarations of the queries and nothing seems helpful. How can one accomplish this?

Comment: just tried that; it gives me all the cells, including those with the description "Type". I can filter from there but it's not The Answer.
i'm also getting a "Argument not assignable to parameter type ByRoleOptions" error on the {description: /name/i} object.
but thanks for the suggestion! i'm definitely closer now.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getAllByRole('cell', {description: /name/i})` to retrieve an array containing the cells in column Name.

Check the array contains a certain value using toContain(item).
https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tocontainitem

An example (using React):

**App.js**

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td id='name'>Name</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td aria-describedby='name'>J Blogs</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td aria-describedby='name'>J Doe</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td aria-describedby='name'>J Hancock</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**App.test.js**

```js
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('retrieves all cells described by name', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const cells = screen.getAllByRole('cell', {description: /name/i});
  const cellValues = cells.map(cell => cell.textContent);
  expect(cellValues).toContain('J Doe');
});
```